# Reference request: Calculus, Linear Algebra, Statistics, Combinatorics, ... Short Overview.

Tags: reference-request, reference-works

I am in the process of creating a personal collection of reference materials for various areas of mathematics, including statistics, combinatorics, calculus, and linear algebra, as well as others such as group theory, set theory, and topology.

The goal is to have a convenient, easily accessible resource for future projects and studies, rather than having to search through a large number of books to find specific properties and information. However, many of the textbooks I am currently using are quite lengthy and not structured in a way that is useful for this purpose.

I am looking for recommendations for texts that could serve as a foundation for my own set of documents. Ideally, these texts would be concise, and cover a range of difficulty levels, from introductory to advanced.

As a first-year student, I am particularly interested in refreshing my knowledge of linear regression and inferential statistics."

Comment: Some universities give that kind of list, but first you should specify the expected level (middle is a bit vague), and in what area you will specialize, as it could change the answer. Are you a student? There is no perfect mathematical library suitable to everybody, especially if you want to keep it small. As is, I fear the question is too broad. For instance, statistics has so many subfields there could be an entire list devoted to them.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut by middle - I mean covering all of the contents of an introductory course but for someone who has already done it. More as a review. 

Also like the post says (all levels are welcome)

Comment: My problem is: I could recommend Brockwell & Davis' *"Time Series: Theory and Methods"* or Agresti's *"Categorical Data Analysis"*, but if you are not going to specialize in statistics, I doubt it would be of any use to you. And all "introductory" courses are likely to not go beyond inferential statistics and linear regression, which will be far from enough if you are really into statistics. Not easy to answer such a question. Do you just want a list to prepare, say, your master's degree? But even it that case, there is some specialization to expect.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I am a first year graduate student who indeed just wants to freshen up his "linear regression and inferentials"

Comment: Ah, you should have started your question with this! :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you going to study applied mathematics (numerical analysis, statistics, etc.) or pure mathematics (maybe abstract algebra, algebraic topology and geometryc, etc.)? I ask because among the books below, some a really for one profile or the other but not really both.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Actually Im studying artificial intelligence in computer science. I just love documentation and list-like comprehensive reference sheets and want to compile them over major mathematical fields (so I can check my notation, terminology, details) and what not. So Im largely going to focus on applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give the Amazon links not to push you to buy (they are often too expensive, and if you can get them at your university library, go ahead!), but to have a look at tables of contents and reviews.

Statistics: Schervish, "[Theory of Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387945466)". Probability would probably(!) be useful: Borovkov, "[Probability Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/144715200X)".

Forget calculus and learn analysis, once and for all :)

Real analysis: J. Yeh "[Real Analysis : Theory of Measure and Integration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814578541)" (covers Lebesgue's integral and a good deal of functional analysis).

Also in analysis: the two Rudin books, "[Principles of Mathematical Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007054235X) and "[Real and Complex Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070542341)"

Groups and linear algebra: either Serge Lang "[Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038795385X)" or Dummit & Foote "[Abstract Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471433349)". They may be too abstract (you will find Galois theory, modules, etc. in them), so if you are only looking after matrix theory, I could suggest Axler "[Linear Algebra Done Right](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3319110799)" (I don't own this one though, but I believe it's quite appreciated). 
If you need *numerical* linear algebra: Golub & Van Loan "[Matrix Computations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1421407949)", Demmel "[Applied Numerical Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898713897)" or Trefethen & Bau "[Numerical Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898713617)"

Topology: Munkres, "[Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004DX5K5K)", but many texts are worth a look, even if they are not as known. I like Newman "[Elements of the Topology of Plane Sets of Points](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486670376)" for instance, and Steen & Seebach "[Counterexamples in Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048668735X)" is a jewel, to really understand the limits of many theorems.

You didn't mention complex analysis, numerical analysis, differential geometry, and many others, so I'll let you update the question if you feel the need.

Comment: Is calculus that bad compared to analysis?

Comment: @Alan No, it's a tongue-in-cheek comment: calculus is often said to be a simplified and less rigorous version of analysis.